# HERE Maps react webpack undefined global

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Using the webpack portion of [this tutorial](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.20.0/dev_guide/topics/get-started-bundling.html) generates error `undefined global` for production build.

Since TerserPlugin code from tutorial is not up to date (chunkFilter [was removed in 3.0.0](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-2020-05-01)). I tried with multiple variations of

```
optimization: {
     minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
         exclude: /mapsjs/
     })],
 }
```

but no luck.

From debugging it, I figured out that the here library is minified twice, because this webpack config made it work

```
optimiszation: {
     minify: false,
}
```

So the question becomes: **how to build HERE maps with webpack 4 and 5?**

P.S. In the end I asked for library when my component mounted:

```
const loadHERE = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'module';
        script.src = 'https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs.bundle.js';
        script.async = true;
        script.onload = resolve;

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, It works for me.

```
optimization: {
     minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({         
     exclude: "mapsjs.bundle.js"
     })],
 }
```